# returning speed sensor reading to zero in python

Tags: python

I am measuring the speed of a rotating wheel in m/s using a hall effect sensor and a small magnet attched to the wheel.

The code is written in python and works fairly well when measuring the speed, distance, rpm etc however when the wheel is stopped the speed will never return to 0m/s.

I have tried modifying the if statement so that if the elapsed time (i.e. the time taken for a revolution) is greater than 3 seconds we can assume the wheel is at rest.

It is probably a simple fix however i can not seem to figure it out, can anyone advise?  Thanks in advance.

**My code**

```
Distance = 0.00
mps = 0
rpm = 0
elapse = 0
sensor = 5
pulse = 0
start_timer = time.time()

def init_GPIO():                                   # initialize GPIO
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_UP)

def calculate_elapse(channel):                     # callback function
        global pulse, start_timer, elapse
        pulse+=1                                   # increase pulse by 1 whenever interrupt occurred
        elapse = time.time() - start_timer         # elapse for every 1 complete rotation made!
        start_timer = time.time()                  # let current time equals to start_timer

def calculate_speed(r_cm):
        global pulse,elapse,rpm,dist_m,Distance,mps
        if elapse !=0 and elapse < 3:              # to avoid DivisionByZero error
                rpm = 1/elapse * 60
                circ_cm = (2*math.pi)*r_cm         # calculate wheel circumference in CM
                dist_m = circ_cm/100               # convert cm to m
                mps = dist_m / elapse              # calculate m/sec      
                Distance = (dist_m*pulse)          # measure distance
                return mps
        else: 
                mps = 0
                return mps

def init_interrupt():
        GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.FALLING, callback = calculate_elapse, bouncetime = 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        init_GPIO()
        init_interrupt()
        while True:
                calculate_speed(3.4)               # call this function with wheel radius as parameter
                print('{0:.0f}rpm     {1:.2f}m/s     {2:.2f}m     Counter:{3}'.format(rpm,mps,Distance,pulse))
                sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing 'mps' from the global variables in 'calculate_speed' ? I would test if returning a global variable isn't screwing the stuff (then you must adapt your script with 'mps=calculate_speed(3.4)')

Answer (score 0):

If the wheel isn't turning, then `calculate_elapse` wont be called. That means `elapse` will never get set to a 'large' (>=3) value and so your `mps = 0` shortcircuit will never be triggered.

Your use of globals deepy upset me, so I had a shot at rewriting this... this is untested but hopefully you'll see why this is a bit nicer:

```
import math
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  # This is my best guess :-)


SENSOR_ID = 5
WHEEL_RADIUS_CM = 3.4


class UnknownRotationError(Exception):
    pass


class WheelTimer:
    MAX_ACCEPTABLE_DURATION = 3.0

    def __init__(self, wheel_radius_cm):
        self.wheel_radius_cm = wheel_radius_cm
        self._wheel_circ_m = ((2 * math.pi) * self.wheel_radius_cm) / 100

        self.num_full_rotations = 0
        self.total_distance_m = 0.0

        self.last_rotation_duration_s = None
        self._rotation_started_time = time.time()

    def complete_rotation(self):
        """Record a completed revolution."""
        self.num_full_rotations += 1
        self.total_distance_m = self._wheel_circ_m * self.num_full_rotations
        now = time.time()
        self.last_rotation_duration_s = self.rotation_started_time - now
        self._rotation_started_time = now

    @property
    def current_rotation_duration(self):
        return self.rotation_started_time - time.time()

    def _validate_rotation(self):
        if not self.last_rotation_duration_s:
            raise UnknownRotationError()
        if self.last_rotation_duration_s > self.MAX_ACCEPTABLE_DURATION:
            raise UnknownRotationError()
        if self.current_rotation_duration > self.MAX_ACCEPTABLE_DURATION:
            raise UnknownRotationError()

    @property
    def current_speed_ms(self):
        self._validate_rotation()
        return self._wheel_circ_m / self.last_rotation_duration_s

    @property
    def current_rpm(self):
        self._validate_rotation()
        return (1.0 / self.last_rotation_duration_s) * 60.0


def init_GPIO():  # initialize GPIO
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(SENSOR_ID, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)


def init_interrupt(callback_func):
    GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_ID, GPIO.FALLING, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_GPIO()
    wheel_timer = WheelTimer(WHEEL_RADIUS_CM)
    init_interrupt(callback_func=wheel_timer.complete_rotation)
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            print('{0:.0f}rpm     {1:.2f}m/s     {2:.2f}m     Counter:{3}'.format(
                wheel_timer.current_rpm,
                wheel_timer.current_speed_ms,
                wheel_timer.total_distance_m,
                wheel_timer.num_full_rotations,
            ))
        except UnknownRotationError:
            print("Wheel moving too slowly to measure!")
```